# Windows 2008 R2 shared drive not able to access folder shared on same server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server (lets says ServerA). The server is on a domain. I have shared a folder ABC on the ServerA and have set its permission to allow access to EveryOne (both NTFS and Share permissions).

The ABC folder is accessible from Windows 7 machine on the same domain. But when I logon to the same server (ServerA) with administrative access and try to access the shared folder ABC as `\\ServerA\ABC`, I get a message "Windows cannot access `\\ServerA\ABC`. You do not have permission to access `\\ServerA\ABC`. Contact your administrator". I am not sure what is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to navigate directly to it and access it from there instead of using a UNC path? If so, it sounds like you might need to add that admin account onto the permissions or into the group assigned to that folder.

Comment: Yes, I am able to navigate directly to the folder and access it from there. I tried adding admin account onto the permissions with Full Control, still no success.